# Firefox session timeout immediately

Tags: firefox, jsp, session-timeout

I have a the following in my header.html:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="<%= session.getMaxInactiveInterval() %>; URL=/nmt/extranet/asp/error.jsp" />
```

and the following in my web.xml

```
  <session-config>
<session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
```

After an hour the session times out and redirects me to the error.jsp in IE and Opera but in Firefox it redirects me immediately.  Does anyone know why this may be occurring or is there something wrong with the ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bothering you guys.  The header page was an html page instead of jsp.  I works fine now.

Thanks for the answers though.

This is still the best place to ask a question and get good answers within a timely manner. :D

Answer (score 0):

Is this just with one firefox install, or have you tried various other machines? Are you sure Firefox is passing the session cookies around correctly? Try the L[ive Http Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829) firefox plugin to see what's going back and forth.

Comment: I'm using firefox 3.0 on Fedora 10 and firefox 3.5 on WinXP.  I will try out the plugin and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting the 60 directly into the META tag, that's seconds not minutes. The session timeout param is in minutes.

That said, it should work the same for all browsers.